# How can I import Volunteer information from a spreadsheet

Tags: civivolunteer

CiviCRM 4.7.24
Wordpress 4.8.x
CiviVolunteer

I have installed CiviVolunteer. I have created a project which I need in order to import some basic volunteer data from a spreadsheet.

I have imported the contacts already, and have a unique ID to match them back with the rest of the data.

Now I need to import the volunteer data. There's not really too much.

From what I can glean from the pretty sparse documentation, you have to import the volunteer information as an activity. But there's no indication of what fields in the import list correspond to.

Do some of them correspond to the project I created above? Or are they their own thing?

I haven't seen any documentation about projects joining to activities and how they all link up.

Is this something i might be able to find in the CiviCRM API Explorer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Fuzion's [API import extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport) if you need an import option that goes beyond the standard Import options. It may not help directly with the volunteer data that goes in the civicrm_volunteer_ tables, but could help with other stuff, like Activities and Relationships.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a look. However, it doesn't make clear how to import volunteer data. Now I'm still learning CiviCRM, so maybe there's something I haven't worked out yet.

I still can't quite work out how to map my data to the relevant fields.

As a side note, I have some of the people volunteering for multiple jobs. I tried making the import field "job1|job2" but I'm not sure that's going to work to import two jobs....

Comment: Hi Norman - sorry I haven't used CiviVolunteer so can't really comment on the data structure involved, so it could be that the above does not actually get you a step ahead. I see that civivol sets up tables called civicrm_volunteer_need civicrm_volunteer_project and civicrm_volunteer_project_contact. If you are familiar with sql then you could potentially do the required via an sql import once you have set up the Projects via the UI